# vue-chartjs not able to update the chart

Tags: vuejs3, vue-chartjs

I'm trying to understand how can I render a chart dynamically so after I can adapt it so can I send data to it trough MQTT so I can display data in real time.

The problem is the following: when I uncomment the `this.speed.push(this.initial_speed + 1)` line I get a `Maximum call stack size exceeded` error. The x axis is rendering dynamically (when the indicated line is commented) but I'm not able to make it work with both the axes.

I attach the sandbox to my code:
[sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/amazing-voice-bsf1s5?file=/src/components/Readings.vue:881-920)

Thank you beforehand.

Comment: Hi, please update your sandbox code, there is not a functional example

Comment: Comment this line out "this.speed.push(this.initial_speed + 1)" in the add method and it will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, honestly I can't find the source of the issue, but using this syntax you can run your add method without problem

```
add() {
  this.created_at.push(this.initial_speed + 1)
  this.initial_speed += 1
  this.speed = [...this.speed, this.initial_speed]
}
```

This problem is something related to the computed property inside the Line component from chartjs, it's not related to something in your code (this is what I can see)

Let me know if everything is fine

Comment: This indeed solves the issue, thank you.

Comment: Nice to know it! please, could you mark my answer as the right one, thanks.